Text overflow Issue in Treemap Visualization using React and Recharts API
I am creating a custom visualization for New Relic using React and the Recharts library. My goal is to display data in a Treemap format. However, I am facing an issue where the text inside the boxes of the treemap is overflowing due to the boxes for the smaller being too small, making it hard to read and sometimes just being a mess.
// Custom content renderer to display name and value inside the Treemap nodes
  renderCustomContent = (props) => {
    let { x, y, width, height, name, value, depth, fill } = props;

    // Ensure minimum width and height to prevent text overflow
    const minWidth = 40;
    const minHeight = 40;
    width = Math.max(width, minWidth);
    height = Math.max(height, minHeight);

    // Skip rendering the root node (depth 0)
    if (depth === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <g>
        <rect
          x={x}
          y={y}
          width={width}
          height={height}
          stroke="white"
          fill={fill} // Use the dynamically assigned color for each node
        />
        <text
          x={x + width / 2}
          y={y + height / 2 - 10}
          textAnchor="middle"
          fill="#000"
          fontSize={14}
          style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}
        >
          {name}
        </text>
        <text
          x={x + width / 2}
          y={y + height / 2 + 10}
          textAnchor="middle"
          fill="#000"
          fontSize={12}
          style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}
        >
          {value}
        </text>
      </g>
    );
  };

I have tried implementing a minimum size for the boxes, however the boxes end up overlapping. I am not sure how to tackle this issue. I have already made it so that the larger values display the full name and the smaller ones a shortened version of the name.

can you create a repproduction in codesandbox? Otherwise it will be quite hard to help
